# how to change the content of a navbar depending on the page you are on, and put the right roots?

Tags: angular, navbar, root

Hi have a navbar in my application and I use the root in order to switch the components.
This is my .html :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <img src="assets/pictures/AVtech.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"alt="">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/desktop">Desktop<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/creationOne">Créer 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/creationTwo">Créer 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/connexion">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And in my app-routing.mudule.ts I have :

```
 { path: 'desktop', component: DesktopComponent },
 { path: 'creationOne', component: CreationOneComponent },
 { path: 'creationTwo', component: CreationTwoComponent },
 { path: 'connexion', component: ConnexionComponent }
```

I want that when I clic in "Login", display an other navBar which replaces the first one.
For exemple in order to have a new navbar with two other roots like that :

```
{ path: 'profil', component: ProfilComponent },
{ path: 'work', component: WorkComponent },
```

Can you help me please ?

I edit my post :

So after reading your advice, I did this :

```
<nav *ngIf="isLoggedIn(); else secondNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <img src="assets/pictures/AVtech.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"alt="">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/desktop">Desktop<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/creationOne">Créer 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/creationTwo">Créer 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/connexion">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<ng-template #secondNavbar>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <img src="assets/pictures/AVtech.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"alt="">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profil">Profil<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/work">Work</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</ng-template>


<div class='container-fluid mt-3'>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And it work well ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ng-template>` to switch between the two navbars and a function like isLoggedIn() that tells if the user is logged in or not.

```
<first-navbar *ngIf="isLoggedIn(); else secondNavbar"></first-navbar>

<ng-template #secondNavbar>
    <second-navbar></second-navbar>
</ng-template>
```